# Does anyone know how to influence abduction site locations?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

Pretty simple question I can't find an answer for.

Basically, I manged to eek out a good start on Impossible, handled the first abduction and UFO interception, but now the second abduction is hitting the worst possible combination of countries, so I'd like to force a "reroll" of those abduction sites, but can't seem to figure out how.

I've tried rerunning the UFO raid the happened a few days before, selling different things in the Gray Market, changing research projects, building new items and/or facilities and hiring new soldiers, but to no effect.

At the same time, I know they're not set in stone, because if I go back to the beginning and just ignore everything unit the second abduction, the sites are different.

Anyone know how to change the abduction mission site locations?

Comment: It's random. I don't know how far back the sites get *picked*, but they *are* random.

Comment: Actually is a 'seeded' random - this means once the seed is generated, you cant just 'load' and try again - you'll get the same result.

Comment: @TheShiftExchange: What you are talking about is that the seed is saved with save data. However the seed will be effectively updated with every roll made so rerunning a UFO raid entirely is likely to generate a different seed by the end (unless exactly the same number of rolls were made). So although you can't load and try again he did say he'd been doing different things, at least some of which would have generated rolls.

Comment: Actually from my experience - there seems to be different seeds for different categories. i.e. the action seed (moving, shooting etc) is a different seed set than in the mission base (waiting for UFOs, which missions you get)

Comment: @HopelessN00b: how often have you been saving you game? My suggestion is to go back to your last In-Mission save before you got the bad series of locations and see what comes up afterwards. The missions you get are randomly seeded, but they are not all predetermined at the game start. It IS possible to reload an old save and get different missions than you did the first time. My guess is that the seeds are generated every time you return to base (reloading a base save yielded the same missions for me), so save frequently, both in mission and upon returning.

Comment: There are some mods out there on xcom.nexusmods.com which enable you to shoot down the UFOs that start abduction missions. If you shoot them down before they can ever start, you'll have one less choice to worry about. They're tough to shoot down in the early game though. Looks like it's a feature that was originally in the game and cut. The mods just re-enable it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't have anything that could change the seed I was getting for those abductions (without loading way back), so I just sucked it up and lost a couple countries on continents I didn't want to.  Oh well.

One thing I've noticed from playing through, however, is that abductions only occur in countries for which there's no satellite coverage, so by planning my deployments a little more strategically (and getting lucky with the terror mission locations), I was able to avoid any more losses - basically, blanket the the three continents with the fewest countries (South America, North America and Africa) with satellites ASAP, and from there on out, you'll only get abductions in Europe and Asia, which makes it much easier to manage panic levels, especially if/when the terror missions also happen on those two continents.

Answer (score 2):

One thing that I have noticed is that you can only get abduction missions in countries that are still in the XCOM program. If you focus your panic-reduction efforts on continents which you want to get the bonuses for (usually North America, Europe and Asia for me), and allow the others to leave the program, you get to the point where you frequently get all abduction site options on the same continent, meaning that it doesn't matter which you choose, provided you are successful, you won't get a panic increase.